# Why doesn't Intent work with setOnItemClickListener?

Tags: java, android, listview, android-intent

I'm trying to make my listItem clickable by invoking the setOnItemClickListener and pass in an intent to start my new activity but it doesn't work.  Basically my intention is to reuse the same activity with different data but for now, I just want to get the clicking functionality in order.  However, this basic functionality doesn't work.

By "doesn't work", I don't mean that the app crashes.  I mean that the listItem click is not invoking the targeted Activity.

I've placed the code in my onCreate:

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        createDatabase();

        listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lvSemesters);
        databaseHelper = new DatabaseHelper(MainActivity.this);
        semesterList = new DatabaseHelper(MainActivity.this).getAllSemesters();
        this.adapter = new SemesterAdapter(MainActivity.this, semesterList);
        floatActionButton = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.addActionButton);


        floatActionButton.setOnClickListener(this);
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);

        listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, CourseActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
    }
```

This is my full MainActivity just in case:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {
    private ListView listView;
    private DatabaseHelper databaseHelper;
    private SQLiteDatabase db;
    private FloatingActionButton floatActionButton;
    private SemesterAdapter adapter;
    List<SemesterEntity> semesterList;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        createDatabase();

        listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lvSemesters);
        databaseHelper = new DatabaseHelper(MainActivity.this);
        semesterList = new DatabaseHelper(MainActivity.this).getAllSemesters();
        this.adapter = new SemesterAdapter(MainActivity.this, semesterList);
        floatActionButton = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.addActionButton);


        floatActionButton.setOnClickListener(this);
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);

        listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, CourseActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
    }

    protected void createDatabase() {
        db = openOrCreateDatabase("semesterDatabase", Context.MODE_PRIVATE, null);
        db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS semesterTable(id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, semester VARCHAR);");
    }

    public void select() {
        databaseHelper = new DatabaseHelper(MainActivity.this);
        semesterList = databaseHelper.getAllSemesters();
        SemesterAdapter adapter = new SemesterAdapter(MainActivity.this, semesterList);
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        int id = v.getId();
        int counter = databaseHelper.getUsersCount();
        if (counter < 8) {
            switch (id) {
                case R.id.addActionButton:
                    String semesterName = "Semester";
                    String query = "INSERT INTO semesterTable (semester) VALUES('" + semesterName + "');";
                    db.execSQL(query);
                    select();
                    break;
            }
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(this, "You can't add more than 8 semesters", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    }

    public void clearTable() {
        db.execSQL("delete from " + DatabaseHelper.TABLE_NAME);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.delete) {
            clearTable();
            select();
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

**EDIT:  I've solved the problem**

Basically I've set up a method in the CardView's onClick XML attribute and created a method in MainActivity with the necessary intent code.

Comment: Tip: You can answer your own question and accept it if you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically I've set up a method in the CardView's onClick XML attribute and created a method in MainActivity with the necessary intent code.

Comment: Suggestion: Use a CursorAdapter with a database instead of ArrayAdapter

Comment: Why CursorAdapter?